# KonvaJS - how to check if Line is inside other Node

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

Looking for help. I need to check if one node (in my case it's `Line`) is inside another node (can be different shapes). In my case, I need to check if the `Red Line` is inside `Blue Node`.

My attempt: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-wing-xmy2pi

#### Edit:

My goal is to check whether a separate node (in my case -> the `Red Line`) is COMPLETELY inside (over) the `Blue Node`. They are both separate nodes (`Red Line` is not a child of the `Blue Box` and vice versa).

The `Blue Node` can be different shapes. Note that I can't check if only the first and last point of the `Red Line` is inside the `Blue Node` (see the image -> it should fail in such case because `Red Line` is NOT completely over the `Blue Node`).

[image]

Comment: Compare the values the rectangles have against each other at the dragend event. You can use [`rect1.getClientRect()`](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Rect.html#getClientRect__anchor) and `rect2.getClientRect()`.

Comment: @Christopher The rectangles are just minimal example. I need to check if any node is inside another. A node can be a polygon with different shapes of dozens of points.

Comment: Then you should edit your question, because now you ask for a complete collision detection of shapes with unknown patterns. Basically you need to test all nodes that exists (in the layer or the whole Stage) against the node you dragged. You can use the result of [Layer.getChildren()](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Layer.html#getChildren__anchor) to do so.

Comment: @Christopher Detection wont help here, because I need to know if a node is completely over (or inside) some other node. `getChildren` wont work either, because it's not a parent. They are separate nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Solution in snippet below and at https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/QWZEKYw. Dear the blue line around so it overlaps / is inside / is outside the polygon and click the 'test button.

Assuming that you know the x,y points of the polygon vertices:

**Test #1 - does the line cross any edge?**

If you think of the polygon edges as being a series of individual lines then you can tackle the first question via the line-line intersection test. There are plenty of solutions on the web, for example see solution for that at [Jeffery Thompson](https://www.jeffreythompson.org/collision-detection/line-line.php).

So what you do is test each edge for collision with the line. Any collision means the line is not fully contained.

Test #2 - is the line inside or outside the shape?

We can use Konva's [Shape.intersects(point)](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Shape.html#intersects__anchor) for this. Since we confirmed in test #1 that the line is either entirely inside or entirely outside the polygon, we can pick any point on the line and call shape.intersects(point) once - if the answer is false then the entire line is outside the polygon, if the answer is true then the line is entirely inside.

[image: Example of using edges as lines for collision detection of line on polygon]

And here is the code from the solution

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: "container",
    width: 1000,
    height: 800,
    draggable: true
  }),
      
  layer = new Konva.Layer({
    draggable: false
  }),
           
  poly = new Konva.Line({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        points: [23, 20, 23, 160, 70, 93, 150, 109, 290, 139, 270, 93],
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        closed: true,
        draggable: true
      }),
      
   line = new Konva.Line({
     x: 130, y: 140,
     points: [0, 0, 100, 50],
     stroke: 'blue',
     strokeWidth: 8,
     draggable: true
   })

layer.add(poly, line);

stage.add(layer);
 
function test(line, polygon){
  
  let hit = false;
  
  // clear collsion marker
    const circles = layer.find('.demoPt');
    if (circles.length > 0){
      for (const circle of circles){
        circle.destroy()
      }
    }  

  // get the end-of-line points
  const e1 = {
    x: line.x() + line.points()[0],
    y: line.y() + line.points()[1],
  }

  const e2 = {
    x: line.x() + line.points()[2],
    y: line.y() + line.points()[3],
  }
    
  
  // Process each edge of the polygon as a line
  for (let i = 0; i < polygon.points().length; i = i + 2){

    // get the line point
    const v1 = {
      x: poly.x() + polygon.points()[i],
      y: poly.y() + polygon.points()[i + 1],
    }

    // for the other end we need the first point if we are on the last point
    let v2
    if (i  === polygon.points().length - 2){
      v2 = {
        x: poly.x() + polygon.points()[0],
        y: poly.y() + polygon.points()[1],
      }  
    }
    else {
      v2 = {
        x: poly.x() + polygon.points()[i+2],
        y: poly.y() + polygon.points()[i + 3],
      }
    }
     
    // Now run the line intersection check    
    const result = lineIntersection(v1.x, v1.y, v2.x,  v2.y, e1.x, e1.y, e2.x, e2.y)
    
    if (result){
      
      // If we have a result then then lines DO interset -- add a circle to indicate
      
      const c1 = new Konva.Circle({
        name: 'demoPt',
        x: result.x,
        y: result.y,
        fill: 'cyan',
        radius: 10
      })
      layer.add(c1)     
      
    }
    else {
    // if we get to here then there are no line collisions.        
    // So check if line is outside of polygon
    
    // we already know one end point of line in e1.
    hit = polygon.intersects(e1)
    
    // show the result
      
    }
    
    $('#result').html('line inside shape = ' + hit)
    
  }
}

$('#test').on('click', function(){
 
  test(line, poly)
})
 

function lineIntersection(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4) {

  // calculate the distance to intersection point
  let denom = ((y4-y3)*(x2-x1) - (x4-x3)*(y2-y1))
  let uA = ((x4-x3)*(y1-y3) - (y4-y3)*(x1-x3)) / denom;
  let uB = ((x2-x1)*(y1-y3) - (y2-y1)*(x1-x3)) / denom;

  // if uA and uB are between 0-1, lines are colliding
  if (uA < 0 || uA > 1 || uB < 0 || uB > 1){
    return null;    
  }
  return {
    x: x1 + (uA * (x2-x1)), 
    y: y1 + (uA * (y2-y1))};

}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
} 
#container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px; 
}
span {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@8/konva.min.js"></script>
<p id='info'>  
  <button id='test'>Test</button> <span id='result'>Is the line inside the shape?</span>
</p> 
<div id="container" class='container'>
```